# What is an English word to block light?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word to mean "make opaque".

I'm thinking, perhaps "obscured" or "block", but neither sound right.

Example: I put electrical tape over the LED lights to *[your word]* them.

Comment: I think you'll have more options if you rephrase the *to* part with a *so (that)* clause.

Comment: In czech, we say stínit, my dictionary translates it as shield, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Both "block" and "obscure" can be used.

"Block" implies that you have eliminated 100% of the light; "obscure" doesn't necessarily imply 100%.

> I blocked the LEDs by putting tape over them.
>
> My view out the window was obscured by the ivy; I could see Mary but couldn't see who she was talking to.

[Block](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/block) (verb definition 1d)

> to shut off from view

[Obscure](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscure) (transitive verb definitions 1 and 2)

> to make dark, dim, or indistinct
>
> to conceal or hide by or as if by covering

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, another option is, simply, to **cover**.

You may also consider **hide**, though that to me implies they were bothersome/irrelevant/unsightly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the word you're looking for would be the verb

**[Opacify](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/opacify)**

> verb -fies, -fying or -fied
>   to make or become opaque

Comment: I don't know that this is a good choice for putting electrical tape over a light, but it is an interesting addition. Opacify is more for changing the state of a substance to make it more opaque. http://www.wordnik.com/words/opacify : "The westering sun slanted in through the window and he didn't bother to push the contact that would **opacify the glass**." It's a subtle distinction though (opaque material does block more light than clear).